# Is there any easier way than HashMap?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

so I'm still fairly new to Java and Android programming.  I have designed a simple Text Lingo Android app.  Everything works well, but I was just wondering if there is an easier way to create my own "dictionary" of words.  Currently...my code involves about 80 lines of

```
HashMap<String> words //new hashMap

words.put("Lol,"laugh out loud");
words.put(someKey, someValue);  //repeat for 80 different words and counting..
```

I don't know much about databases, although I don't know if that would really make it easier.  Just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: That looks very easy, is there something about it that's giving you problems?

Comment: Not necessarily, I was just wondering whether or not there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: I think that's probably your best bet, what you have now. You could always put it in an Excel spreadsheet and write code so your program can access the information from it, but a file reader and more complex concepts would have to be implemented. I think a map is probably the way to go at this point. You may be able to split your definitions hashmap into another method, just to clean it up a little bit. That would also make it available to other methods if you decide to extend its usage.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, forgot this was Android =P Stick with the map, that's really the only reasonable way to do it

Comment: Ha...okay.  Maybe I'm just lazy. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you have shown looks pretty easy but time consuming. The only other idea I could have would be if you have the words in a .csv file you could read the file, then split the string on the delimiter (usually a comma) then iterate over the string array.

That's only faster if you already have a file with the words in.

Comment: I was about to post very similar answer, there is not much to shorten your way

Answer (score 0):

There is no shorter way indeed. Though it is possible to store the data somewhere online in a XML file and load/parse this data only when you need it. you'll have to make a network connection. [See this link.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, I like that idea, but that's more complex than what I want to go with this.